# Spring DatasourceTransactionManager not release connection after commit/rollback

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbc, transactions, spring-jdbc

I have an Enterprise Application (ear) deployed in this configuration enviroment:

Weblogic 12c (12.1.1) + Oracle RAC 11g (release 2). 
Web Module is an MVC application, implemented with Struts 2 and Spring-framework (3.2.2) for core services. Spring JDBC is used for database access with simple JdbcTemplate for single statements and DatasourceTransactionManager for complex ones. I noticed a strange behavior when I enable Weblogic jdbc logs. When I start a new transaction, I can see jdbc info logs about transaction creation, retriving jdbc connection from weblogic datasource pool and setting autocommit property to false value over connection itself. But I can't see transaction releasing connection log, and restoring autocommit flag to true value after commit/rollback invocation. 
It's possible that Spring Transaction Manager does not release jdbc connection and does not restore "autocommit" value flag (to true)? After a while I can see within my application some persistent locks on db tables, causing an overall defect of my application and that I would not have depended on the behavior of the transaction manager.
Has anyone noticed a similar behavior? 
Is it possible that jdbc connection is not released by the framework and it can compete in multiple transactions (as seen in jdbc log)?

Thanks

Paolo

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using managed `DataSource` from WebLogic (JNDI?) you have to use managed `TransactionManager` as well:

```
<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
```

should be enough:

```
if (weblogicPresent) {
    return WEBLOGIC_JTA_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_CLASS_NAME;
}
```

And it is instead of that `DatasourceTransactionManager`.

Comment: Right, I've configured a JNDI Datasource in Weblogic 12c. My fear is that such a change on spring transaction manager configuration (from DataSourceTransactionManager to JtaTransactionManager) can cause other failures in the application.

Comment: I used that pattern (managed DS and managed TX) in the many Spring applications. They worked well on JBOSS, WebLogic, WebSphere without any changes. Hope they are in production even now...